# How to group by with array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataframe **df_my** that looks like this

```
       Rows   Seq    Alg          iMap_x
0      1000   1      Max(1,2)      12
1      1000   2      Min(4)        37
2      1000   3      Max(1,2)      28
3      1000   4      Max(1,2)      18
4      1000   5      Sum()         33
..
134    1000   135    Min(4)        04
135    1000   136    Sum()         11
136    1000   137    Max(1,2)      24
```

I want to have a new dataframe that group by **Alg** and have array of **iMap_x**

so it will look like this

```
       Alg           iMap_x
0      Max(1,2)      [12,28,18,..,24]
1      Min(4)        [37,..,04]
4      Sum()         [33,..,11]
```

I know that I can group by and sum or find the average

```
df_my[["Alg","iMap_x"]].groupby(by="Alg").sum()
```

but I do not know how to make an array !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df[["Alg", "iMap_x"]].groupby("Alg").agg(list).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
        Alg            iMap_x
0  Max(1,2)  [12, 28, 18, 24]
1    Min(4)           [37, 4]
2     Sum()          [33, 11]
```

---

DataFrame used:

|  | Rows | Seq | Alg | iMap_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 1 | Max(1,2) | 12 |
| 1 | 1000 | 2 | Min(4) | 37 |
| 2 | 1000 | 3 | Max(1,2) | 28 |
| 3 | 1000 | 4 | Max(1,2) | 18 |
| 4 | 1000 | 5 | Sum() | 33 |
| 134 | 1000 | 135 | Min(4) | 4 |
| 135 | 1000 | 136 | Sum() | 11 |
| 136 | 1000 | 137 | Max(1,2) | 24 |